# GitKraken : fetching pull requests failed

Tags: gitkraken

I've just installed a free version of GitKraken and logged myself on github.
The software is working but when I pull a branch, I've always a red warning popup telling me "fetching pull requests failed"

[image]

Have you ever experienced that? Did I miss something in the configuration?

PS: my repositories are private

Answer (score 10):

GitKraken can definitely work with private repos, but it would need to be authorized.  Would you be able to login to GitHub using an account that can manage the organization, then click on the organization, then click 'settings' at the top, then 'third party access' on the left? Then you can either remove restrictions at the top to allow all third party apps approved by users, or click on the requested apps in the middle, then click on 'GitKraken', and select 'Grant Access'.

If the issue persists, would you be able to try logging out and then back in?  You can click the button in the upper right and select 'login to another account' then login again.  Then when you login using your GitHub credentials to configure the authentication again.

Comment: Hi Keif and thanks for your response. I don't see GitKraken appearing in the 'Third-party access' section and I don't want to remove all restrictions for my company. But unfortunately I don't see a way to add an approval on a new app. Have you some advices? (I try to relog on kraken but it doesn't change indeed since it's not approved :/)

Comment: Check out GitHub's page for more information on authorization.  https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-with-third-party-applications/#third-party-applications-and-organizations

Comment: Thanks, I was finally able to authorize it on my account and also on my entreprise account. What I did is unauthorize the app from my personnal settings, then restarting Kraken that redirect me to github approval page, and here there was the option for the company!
Unfortunately even after that change and Kraken relogging and Kraken restart, I still have the error message :/

Comment: @KeifKraken I'm experiencing this too.  My organization has third-party application restrictions.  I'm not particularly interested in trying to convince our admin to authorize GitKraken, but I would like to make the error message go away.  Is there any way to disable the pull requests feature (ideally on a per-repo basis)?

Comment: @jonwithoutanh what works for me is to delete my repo, clone again from url (not from a particular type of host), and use the origin url with "<user>@<host>" instead of "<host>". I'm not sure if this depends on other factors like my configured authentications.
Edit: drop-creating isn't even necessary, just had to add <username>@ to the origin url and fetch it.